# Failed to get default contexts and file mode for storage files

Tags: system-error, twrp, asus-transformer-infinity

I'm trying to flash a new ROM to my Asus Transformer Infinity (TF700T).  I unlocked it and installed TWRP 2.8.3.0, but when I launch the recovery, the output screen immediately displays the following:

```
Updating partition details...
... done
Full SELinux support is present.
E:Failed to get default contexts and file mode for storage files.
MTP Enabled
```

The `Failed` line above appears in red on the screen, while nothing else does.  I managed to get the CROMBI-KK ROM installed, but it took quite a few tries.  If I configure it for F2FS file system (which I want to use), the F2FS conversion succeeds but the install fails outright.  Other settings just cause an infinite loading screen after install.

Is there anything I can do to fix the storage device error?

Is it related to the failure of F2FS, or is there anything else I can do to install with F2FS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted this question over at the XDA developers forum and we have it figured out, if not completely resolved. Turns out the TWRP error was something introduced in the version 2.8.3.0, but is not present in previous versions. I have a different TF700t that had version 2.8.1.0 installed (the version immediately before the error came in). It did not have the error, but when I upgraded it to 2.8.3.0 the error appeared. When I downgraded the TWRP on both my devices to 2.8.1.0, the error went away on both.

Team Win released version 2.8.4.0 a few days ago, so I tried installing it. Unfortunately, it still displays the error.

As for the F2FS error, I found out that you should only convert the `/data` location to F2FS. The `/system` and `/cache` locations should stay at EXT4. Once I changed this, the install went thru just fine using F2FS.